# JMS test util for junit or spock

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, spock, activemq-artemis

I'm looking for a JMS client which I can use in some end to end tests. The client shall allow me to connect to external broker and receive or send events to topics and queues.

Tests are end to end and the whole system is running which means:

- no mocking shall be done
- no bean proxying or similar
- in general there is no access to JVM(s) that system is running on
- tests are running on a sperate JVM or potentially a separate machine

I also want the solution to be as generic and broker independent as possible but I'm currently using following stack:

tests:

- spock (on top of junit)

application:

- spring boot
- artemis client

borker:

- artemis 2.4

At first this question may seem similar to some other JMS-JUnit questions asked but it is actually not due to above specific requirements.

Comment: Are you using the Artemis core client directly or the Artemis JMS client implementation (i.e. JMS API implemented on top of the Artemis core protocol)? If you aren't using the Artemis JMS client, why not? If you are using the Artemis JMS client why is it not suitable for your purpose? Just about any JMS application will be independent of the broker implementation (that's what APIs do, after all). If the broker is already running you can just use the JMS client to connect to it and run tests just like any other kind of remote application.

Comment: in the application itself, i'm using artemis with spring's JMS template so I should be theoretically independent of broker. In tests I want to have a similar approach and was hoping for a simpler setup than creating all the boatware around JMS client on my own.

Comment: I also found `artemis-junit` with some prepared JUnit rules. thats exactly the direction I want to go but it seems not to support secured external broker (no username and password).

Comment: Have you looked at JMS 2.0 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms20-1947669.html)? There's really no bloat there like there was with JMS 1.1. Why can't you simply create JUnit tests using JMS 2.0? That will be broker independent with no bloat and minimal external dependencies. If you use `artemis-junit` your tests will not be broker independent.

Comment: @JustinBertram I'm using JMS 2.0, but lets say I want to create JMS client on my own. First step is to create a connection factory, where would I get it from or which class shall I use to initialize as my connection factory resource?

Comment: "Admin" objects like connection factories and destinations can be "looked up" in JNDI (which is the standards-based approach) or simply instantiated (using Artemis-specific classes). You can see lots of demonstrations of the JNDI approach in the examples shipped with Artemis (e.g. https://git.io/vx60J). This approach is also discussed in the JMS specification and lots of other JMS tutorials on the Internet. You can see an example of the Artemis-specific at https://git.io/vx60t (Note: the connection factory here uses the default URL, you can pass your own URL in the constructor).

Comment: @JustinBertram thanks for the antwort. as for instantiating the classes from vendor specific implementations (here Artemis), I don't have a problem here and I'm currently using this approach. I was just looking for a (probably small) library that makes it easier to do so. This is where I found `artemis-junit` and hacked it a bit so that it works as I need it. but would be nice if I could use it from begining like that.

Comment: @JustinBertram one more thing, which is probably out of scope of this question, is the JNDI lookup. I'm familiar with JNDI (or at least I think so) in both container based environments (like Java EE containers) and Java SE environment. but in this case, what I don't understand is, if we are talking about Java SE who is putting those objects in JNDI that we could look them up? and what is the implementation behind them?

Comment: I just found this which makes everything more clear: https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/2.4.0/using-jms.html

Comment: In your original question you say, "I also want the solution to be as generic and broker independent as possible..." Using `artemis-junit` or instantiating admin objects is *not* generic or broker independent. It is the opposite - specific and broker-dependent. However, it would be fairly simple to fulfill the "generic or broker independent" requirement by using the APIs that were created for this task (i.e. JMS & JNDI). If you care about this requirement why are you using broker-specific classes? If you don't care about this requirement then why is it listed in your question? It's confusing.

Comment: my first impression from `artemis-junit` was that its using JMS API but now I know its not. so I decided to write the client on my own now using JMS API. However I think even using the JNDI is not exactly generic as some implementation has to be provided anyway.

Comment: Of course implementations have to be provided. Both JMS and JNDI are **APIs** which are backed by specific implementations (i.e. from Artemis in this case). With JMS you just put the implementation classes on the classpath, and with JNDI you must also provide specific properties to tell the InitialContext where the implementation is and how to construct it. You can provide the JNDI properties in code or via a properties file named `jndi.properties` on the classpath. The benefit of properties file is that it is more pluggable since you don't have to change any code to change implementations.

Comment: thanks for bearing with me all through the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments I would recommend you go with JMS 2 & JNDI so that your tests can be 100% broker independent and free of bloat (JMS 2 is much better than 1.1 in that regard).